# How to pass template reference variable to parent controller (not the same controller)

Tags: angular

child.html

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Recipient's email address</label>
     <input name="email" type="email" #custEmail="ngModel" required validate-email/>
</div>
```

Child.ts

```js
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild} from '

@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    templateUrl: './child.html',
})
export class InvoicePreviewSendComponent {

    @ViewChild('custEmail') email;

    log() {
        console.log(this.email.value);
        console.log(this.email);
    }
}
```

Parent.ts

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, Inject, Output, ViewChild, SecurityContext} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    templateUrl: './parent.html'
})
export class InvoiceDetailsComponent {
    @ViewChild('preview') preview;

    private save() {
        this.preview.log(); //works
        console.log(this.preview.email); //undefined
    }
}
```

patent.html

```html
..
..
    <child #preview></child>
    <button (click)=save()>
..
..
```

So, as mentioned in code, `this.preview.log()` works, but `this.preview.email` is `undefined`. I though with `@ViewChild` component it should make email as the property of the `#preview`. How to access email to the parent element?

Comment: Please provide an example on stackblitz reproducing the issue

Comment: Did you forget to add ngModel to your input?